# Remote SSH connection advice

Tags: centos, ssh, security

I've recently set up port-forwarding for ssh on my server (CentOS 7). I'm also using a custom port for ssh (2211)

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2211/tcp --permanent
```

This works fine I can ssh to the server from the internet however I was wondering if there are any other steps I need to take to keep the server safe.

Any advice or past experiences would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tutorials:

https://serverfault.com/questions/616435/centos-7-firewall-configuration

and

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-firewalld-on-centos-7